# Change .product-item-name font-weight to bold

Tags: magento2, theme, less, luma-theme, parent-child-theme

How to change `.product-item-name` (see image) *font-weight* to bold in my Magento 2 child theme? My parent theme is Luma theme. I can't find in which less file:

```
.product-item-name, .product.name a {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

is defined? What is best practice to make it bold?

[image]

Comment: Please first try to put first inline & then important in CSS

Comment: @Ankit Shah but where, in which less file is `font-weight: 400` defined?